# How to Create Monthly Flags in R Based on Follow-up Data Ranges

Tags: r

Newbie to R.

I have a dataset with columns such as "Pat_ID", "baseline", and several "followup_" columns. Each "followup_" column contains follow-up values for specific months after a baseline measurement. I want to create new variables in R to flag whether a follow-up value falls within specific monthly ranges.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
sampledata <- data.frame(
 Pat_ID = c(1123, 1134, 1138, 1139),
 baseline = c("0", "0", "0", "0"),
 followup_1 = c(97, 89, NA, 95),
 followup_2 = c(NA, 168, NA, 245),
 followup_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
 followup_4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
 followup_5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
 followup_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA),
)
```

I want to create new variables, such as '1_month', '2_month', '3_month', ..., '12_month'. These variables should be set to "1" if a follow-up value falls within the respective monthly range, or "0" if not. The monthly ranges are defined as follows:

```
1_month = ≤30
2_month = >30 and ≤60
3_month = >60 and ≤90
4_month = >90 and ≤120
5_month = >120 and ≤150
6_month = >150 and ≤180
7_month = >180 and ≤210
8_month = >210 and ≤240
9_month = >240 and ≤270
10_month = >270 and ≤300
11_month = >300 and ≤330
12_month = >330 and ≤365
```

The Output table should look like this :

```
Pat_ID, 1_month, 2_month, 3_month, 4_month, 5_month, 6_month, 7_month, 8_month, 9_month, 10_month, 11_month, 12_month
1123, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1134, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1138, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1137, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

I tried for loop but it did not work for me.

Comment: use mutate and case_when

Comment: Hey! Is it possible for you to help me with the code? I am a newbie and I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a shorter approach, but this works. We can express your monthly range table as  `(value - 1) %/% 30 + 1`, since that will count how many 30-day periods had been completed the day before, and add one to that. So 1-30 will get 1, 31-60 will get 2, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
sampledata |>
  pivot_longer(-c(Pat_ID, baseline)) |>
  select(-name, -baseline) |>
  filter(!is.na(value)) |>
  mutate(mo = (value - 1) %/% 30 + 1, value = 1) |>
  distinct(Pat_ID, mo, value) |> # added so only one meeting per qtr is counted
  complete(Pat_ID, mo = 1:12, fill = list(value = 0)) |>
  mutate(mo = paste0(mo, "_month")) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = mo, values_from = value, values_fill = 0)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  Pat_ID `1_month` `2_month` `3_month` `4_month` `5_month` `6_month` `7_month` `8_month` `9_month` `10_month` `11_month` `12_month`
   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1   1123         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         0          0          0          0
2   1134         0         0         1         0         0         1         0         0         0          0          0          0
3   1139         0         0         0         1         0         0         0         0         1          0          0          0
```

Comment: When I tried to run the last line, the following error popped up:`Error in `pivot_wider()`:
! Can't convert `fill` <double> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: Is that running with the example data or with other data?

Comment: I run with this data:sam = data.frame(Pat_ID = c(1123, 1134, 1138, 1139),
                 baseline = c("0", "0", "0", "0"),
                 followup_1 = c(97, 89, NA, 29),
                 followup_2 = c(NA, 168, NA, 245),
                 followup_3 = c(NA, 65, NA, NA),
                 followup_4 = c(NA, NA, 92, NA),
                 followup_5 = c(150, NA, NA, NA),
                 followup_6 = c(NA, NA, 174, NA),
                 followup_7 = c(195, 120, NA, NA),
                 followup_8 = c(33, NA, 90, 230),

Comment: followup_9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 255),
                 followup_10 = c(88, 5, NA, 285),
                 followup_11 = c(NA, 310, 4, NA),
                 followup_12 = c(NA, NA, 345, 123))

Comment: In that 2nd set of data, 1134 has two appointments in the 3_month range and 1139 has 2 in the 9_month range, which makes the pivot_wider ambiguous -- should those appear as 1's in the output? If so, let's add `  distinct(Pat_ID, mo, value) |>` before the `complete()` line.

Comment: @JonSpring Your code is great. I have a few questions. 1- When I run your code the output is exactly what i am looking for but after "12_month" the order of the month is not same. Example after 12_month instead of "13_month" there is "16_month" followed by "13_month", "17_month", "18_month", "15_month", "14_month", "19_month", "22_month", "21_month" and "20_month". Why is it so?

Comment: @JonSpring 2) 2) I have a total of 852 obs (rows). When I run the code it provides the output with 692 obs, because of `filter(!is.na(value))`. When I re-run the code without `filter(!is.na(value))` function it does provide me with 852 obs but has an additional column named "NA_month" which is filled with "1" for every row. How to correct this ?

Comment: I assumed incorrectly that your data only went out 12 months. It might get straightened out if you replace `mo = 1:12` with `mo = 1:22` or whatever is the largest value, or if you add `arrange(mo)` as the third-to-last line.

Comment: Yes, it worked everything is in a order, but I still have this "NA_month" column at the end of the dataset. I am curious to know what it is? Surprisingly, it it filled with "1" throughout the column. Can you help me know what it is?

Comment: Do you have any other non-numeric columns besides pat_id and baseline?

Comment: @JonSpring No i don't have any other non-numeric columns

Answer (score 0):

I used the following sample dataset:

```
sam = data.frame(Pat_ID = c(1123, 1134, 1138, 1139),
                 baseline = c("0", "0", "0", "0"),
                 followup_1 = c(97, 89, NA, 29),
                 followup_2 = c(NA, 168, NA, 245),
                 followup_3 = c(NA, 65, NA, NA),
                 followup_4 = c(NA, NA, 92, NA),
                 followup_5 = c(150, NA, NA, NA),
                 followup_6 = c(NA, NA, 174, NA),
                 followup_7 = c(195, 120, NA, NA),
                 followup_8 = c(33, NA, 90, 230),
                 followup_9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 255),
                 followup_10 = c(88, 5, NA, 285),
                 followup_11 = c(NA, 310, 4, NA),
                 followup_12 = c(NA, NA, 345, 123))
```

First, I grouped the dataset by `Pat_ID`, then I use `mutate` to create the variables you wanted with `ifelse` (You can change this part of code according to the code of Jon Spring. His code is very short and elegant.) Then, I replace `NA` with 0 by using `mutate_at`.

```
sam %>% group_by(Pat_ID) %>% 
        mutate(month_1 = ifelse(followup_1 <= 30,1,0),
               month_2 = ifelse(30 <= followup_2 & followup_2 <= 60,1,0),
               month_3 = ifelse(60 < followup_3 & followup_3 <= 90,1,0),
               month_4 = ifelse(90 < followup_4 & followup_4 <= 120,1,0),
               month_5 = ifelse(120 < followup_5 & followup_5 <= 150,1,0),
               month_6 = ifelse(150 < followup_6 & followup_6 <= 180,1,0),
               month_7 = ifelse(180 < followup_7 & followup_7 <= 210,1,0),
               month_8 = ifelse(210 < followup_8 & followup_8 <= 240,1,0),
               month_9 = ifelse(240 < followup_9 & followup_9 <= 270,1,0),
               month_10 = ifelse(270 < followup_10 & followup_10 <= 300,1,0),
               month_11 = ifelse(300 < followup_11 & followup_11 <= 330,1,0),
               month_12 = ifelse(330 < followup_12 & followup_12 <= 365,1,0)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("month")), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) %>%
  select(month_1:month_12)
```

I hope this code can help you to understand more about `tidyverse`.

Also, a variable name must start with a letter and can be a combination of letters, digits, period(.)
and underscore(*). If it starts with period(.), it cannot be followed by a digit.
A variable name cannot start with a number or underscore (*).

Ref:https://www.w3schools.com/r/r_variables_name.asp

Comment: Thank you so much for the code! I appreciate it. It worked.